# My function is only working inside of the else in an if statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, function, get

If you need the edit function, please let me know. Anyhow, I'm going through a JSON table and getting the ID of an item on ROBLOX. In case you don't work with ROBLOX, we'll use letters. If A's name is B's asset ID, then change A's name to B's name. That's basically what I want to do, but it's not working. Here's my if statement.

```
function loop(page) {
    $.get("https://search.roblox.com/catalog/json?Subcategory=1&CreatorID=62277089&CurrencyType=0&pxMin=0&pxMax=0&SortType=3&SortAggregation=5&SortCurrency=0&IncludeNotForSale=true&LegendExpanded=false&Category=1&PageNumber=" + page).success(function(data) {
        console.log("On page: " + page);
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var prevName = data[i].Name;

            if (!isNaN(prevName)) {
                console.log("Name was Number, changing...")
                $.get("https://www.roblox.com/item.aspx?id=" + Number(prevName)).success(function(data) {
                    var name = $("h1.notranslate", data).text();
                    edit(data[i].AssetId, name);
                    console.log("Changed to " + name);
                });
            } else {
                edit(data[i].AssetId, prevName);
            }
        }
    });
}

for (var i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
    loop(i);
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: please post the full code. What is `prevName`? Where it is declared?

Answer (score 0):

Both of your `$.get` functions return data into the `data` variable. Try this

```
...
if (!isNaN(prevName)) {
    console.log("Name was Number, changing...")
    $.get("https://www.roblox.com/item.aspx?id=" + Number(prevName)).success(function(data2) {
       var name = $("h1.notranslate", data2).text();
       edit(data[i].AssetId, name);
       console.log("Changed to " + name);
    });
} else {
    edit(data[i].AssetId, prevName);
}
...
```

Comment: Wouldn't matter bc scopes.